# Why can't I have property named 'retain' when using XCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, clang

In XCode 4.6.2 ARC, if you have some property in a class named 'retain', either the IDE or the compiling stack will do something funny, making the class can't be used in the usual pattern: `[[MyClass alloc] init]`.

For instance, if I define a class Foo as

```
// Foo.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MosquittoMessage : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL retain;

-(id)init;

@end

// Foo.m

#import "Foo.h"

@implementation MosquittoMessage

-(id) init
{
  self = [super init];
  return self;
}

@end
```

It will compile and run, however, I can't use

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
```

to create foo. The above statement in run time will set foo to nil. I traced the problem using the debugger and found that alloc in fact returned a valid Foo, yet inside init, it got deallocated for some reason and the returned self is nil.

Anyone has any idea about this 'bug' in XCode or the compiling system?

ADDED:

Sure 'retain' is reserved in Obj-C, my question is why didn't the compiler complain if it's not allowed? Instead, it generated wrong code.

Comment: If the compiler didn't error out on that property, it is a bug.  Please file it!!

Comment: If you absolutely have to call your property `retain`, you can make it work by giving the getter a different name: `@property (nonatomic, getter = isRetained) BOOL retain;`. That way `yourObject.retain` doesn't collide with `[NSObject retain]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`retain` is a method of NSObject.

```
- (id)retain;
```

Behind the scenes, ARC is likely changing your code to the following, before compiling.

```
Foo *foo = [[[Foo alloc] init] retain];
```

But by setting up a BOOL property called retain, you've told the compiler there is a

```
- (BOOL)retain;
```

So rather than foo being assigned the id returned by NSObject's retain method, it's being assigned the BOOL returned by your retain method.  And if you haven't defined a method, by the nil that's in the iVar _retain.

[edit]You didn't get an error because it's perfectly legal to overload a superclass method with your own replacement. Just not very useful in this case.

It doesn't seem to be a problem as such. All languages have reserved words that you shouldn't use. One can think of the methods of NSObject as just being part of the reserved word list.  (Thought it isn't really a reserved word of Obj-C.  NSObject is part of Apple's API, not Obj-C as such.)

Comment: Indeed, I tried to change the retain property to int and set the value in init method, the foo is set to the int value. Thanks for your explanation. Someone should file this bug to Apple, so that the compiler generate error in such case.

Comment: As I say, it's not strictly a bug. It's legal to override NSObject methods. And there are cases when it's actually done. For example the old pre-ARC way of creating a singleton class overrides various NSObject methods, including retain.  See the last code block here: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: I think most app developers care about getting things done, rather than figuring out the detailed syntax of the programming language. Apple, and any tools they made should try hard to ease the dev process. Like generate at least warning if such pitfalls can happen. In this sense, Apple should see it as a bug.

Comment: You should file a bug report. The compiler complains if you try to implement a -retain method in ARC code. It should also complain if you try to synthesize a property named -retain (automatically or manually).

Comment: @GregParker Overriding `-retain`, even in ARC, is not a bug. Using `-retain` under ARC is a bug.  ARC is adding it's own `retain` and `release` calls behind the scenes, which you don't know the specifics of, so it's not possible for you to add your own without screwing ARC up. But overriding retain, is perfectly possible, and won't cause any errors, so long as your overridden version calls super, and returns it's value. You could for example debug ARC itself by overriding `-retain` and `-release`, and do logging from them.

Comment: Steve, Greg is saying that it's a bug that the compiler doesn't error out when you create a property named `retain`, because it _is_ an error under ARC to have a method named `retain` (and having a property means you have a method with the same name). See ["Memory management methods"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id45) in Clang's ARC doc.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Thanks for that. Yes, it's a bug then.

Answer (score 5):

A property is merely syntactic sugar for a method call. So a `retain` property implies a `retain` method. But there is *already* a `retain` method, and you're forbidden to call it by ARC.

What you've encountered is really a case of the fact that everything in Objective-C is one vast namespace. You don't want *anything* to have the same name as something that already exists - you can make a name conflict, and get a warning at best or break your app's functionality at worst. I once broke my app by naming a property `firstResponder`; even though no *public* method has this name, evidently such a method exists behind the scenes, and I was accidentally subverting it.